# Spherical coordinates $x:(0,2\pi)\times (0,\pi)\to S^2$, shouldn't it be $S^3$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

I'm reading a book about differential geometry and there's a part where he talks about the standar spherical coordinates on $S^2$, which are given by:

$$x:(0,2\pi)\times (0,\pi)\to S^2, x(\theta, \phi) = (\cos\theta\sin\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi, \cos\phi)$$

Shouldn't it be in $S^3$?

Comment: The 2 refers to the dimension of the sphere, not to the dimension of the ambient space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. [$S^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere) is the ordinary sphere embedded in three dimensions. $S^3$ would have $4$ coordinates in Cartesian form.

It is called $S^2$ since it is a $2D$ surface in the sense that any point on it can be described by two coordinates ($\theta, \phi$) as your mapping $x$ shows.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, so we have three coordinates $ (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ but it is a surface because, as you can see: $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1$ so it is the surface of a sphere in the $3D$ space.

Answer (score 0):

The sphere is considered to be a 2-dimensional surface embedded in 3-dimensional space.  But the embedding is sort of extraneous.  It's not as handy, but the same map embeds in 2-dimensional space.

Comment: I think that the second statement is not true (indeed, not even meaningful mathematically). The map $x$, whose codomain is $\mathbb R^3$, surely doesn't embed anything into 2D-space (i.e., $\mathbb R^2$).

Comment: How do you picture projective spaces?

Comment: For $RP^2$, I think of Boy's surface, but lift it into $R^5$ by adding two extra coordinates along the double curves. For others, I guess I'd say that I don't "picture" them at all. But my way of visualizing things has no impact on the semantics of your statement.